# IIS 6 + MVC 3 + CSS - With Chrome/FireFox/Safari the css styles are not displaying >>HELP

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, firefox, iis

I deployed my mvc 3 app to IIS 6 (with ntlm) and the site functions great with Internet Explorer (IE) however when I try and view the site with Chrome/FireFox/Safari the styles which are located in Site.css are not being applied.

I can see in Firebug that the css was found.  Within Firebug however I get an message "There are no rules. You can create a rule."....so the css is found however for some reason it doesn't look for FireFox (or others) as a style sheet?

The css is reference via the _layout.cshtml as shown...

```
<link href="https://{www.testsite.com}/{applicationName}/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am at wits end as to why it is not rendering for me?  Ideas?

Comment: In FireFox when I look at css Firebug says "There are no rules. You can create a rule."

Comment: how can you tell your css file is served to the client, perhaps you have 404 on that  request, use Fiddle or some network capturing tool to validate the file is actually served

Comment: It's more likely that the CSS file is served with the wrong content type. Web server should be configured to serve CSS files as `text/css`. IE does not care but other browsers do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to this problem was to add a custom MIME type associating .CSS files with the type "text/css".